# best way to combine an event-trigger and an additional condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, conditional-statements

is there a way to combine in **one expressinon** for example:

1. `$('.class').click()`
2. `if( foo == 'bar')`

I mean,

when .class item is clicked and var is true, do something

something that puts this toggether

```
$('.class').click(function(){
    if(foo == 'bar'){
        //do something
    }
})
```

Comment: i dont get it. doesnt the second, as it is, work for you?

Comment: yes but i thoght that would be a simpler way to do it..

Comment: That's the way to do it. Of course you can extend jQuery and add a new method if you want to.

Comment: simpler than this? i don't think so!

Comment: you can add `$.clickif(var, equals, function() {});` method to jQuery, and in this method `if (var = equals && typeof callback == 'function') callback(); ` Should I post it, like an answer with details, or it's not what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending of your test case you can try to use jquery selector;

for example:

if `.class` is an `</a>` tag you can have like this:

```
$('a[href=#^"'+foo+'"].class').click(function(){ /* */ });
```

if it is an `<input/>` something like this

```
$('input[value="'+foo+'"].class').click(function(){ /* */ });
```

obviously `foo` should be a `global`

> - demo: http://jsbin.com/eyivif/2

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, this seems to be the best way to do it. But as a proof of concept, you could extend jQuery with:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.cond_click = function(condition, handler) {
        return this.click(function() {
           if(condition.apply(this, arguments)) {
               handler.apply(this, arguments);
           }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Which can be used as:

```
$('.class').cond_click(function(){
    return foo === 'bar';
}, function() {
    // do something
});
```